# Load all nested entities

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

Is it possible to load all of nested entities?

I have tree structure and I want to load ALL of childs.

I'm using

```
_context.Trees
        .Include(x => x.Children)
        .ThenInclude(x => x.Children)
        .FirstOrDefaultAsync(x => x.Id == treeId);
```

but it doesn't return all of nested entities. Ony 2 levels, or if I add next TheInclude it returns next level.

How to get all of nested entities?

Comment: You can't, I mean if it is recursive you should try to flattern your table and build you tree after

Comment: Lazy loading isn't currently supported in entity framework core you need to .Include all entities in your query.

Comment: `FromSql` with recursive SQL query if your database supports it is the only option. Or load the whole table in memory (the navigation property fixup will link the objects) and then take what you need - e.g. `_context.Trees.ToList().FirstOrDefault(x => x.Id == treeId);`